# NPM stop working in Visual Studio 2015 after node.js Upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2015

I had to upgrade my machine Node.js and NPM to fix the Long Path issue in Windows, but this broke VS 2015.

I tried to reinstall VS 2015 but without any success.

When I try to install any package from VS 2015 the console pop this message below:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json at
>   'C:\Users\FilipeAugusto\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json':
>   Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may
>   contain objects with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may contain objects
>   with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. ---> System.ArgumentException: Can not
>   add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.ValidateToken(JToken o, JToken existing) 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken
>   item, Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken item,
>   Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
>   content, Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.Add(Object content)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.AddValue(JValue value, JsonToken
>   token)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.WriteNull()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEndObject()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.Close()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject(JsonReader
>   reader)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource.WrapExceptionAndRethrow(String
>   fullPathToFile, Exception ex)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.DirectoryPackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullDirectoryPath)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmController.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json at
>   'C:\Users\FilipeAugusto\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json':
>   Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may
>   contain objects with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. --->
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading
>   package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may contain objects
>   with duplicate properties.
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. ---> System.ArgumentException: Can not
>   add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.ValidateToken(JToken o, JToken existing) 
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken
>   item, Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.InsertItem(Int32 index, JToken item,
>   Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.AddInternal(Int32 index, Object
>   content, Boolean skipParentCheck)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.Add(Object content)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.AddValue(JValue value, JsonToken
>   token)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.WriteNull()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEndObject()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenWriter.Close()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject(JsonReader
>   reader)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.ReaderPackageJsonSource..ctor(TextReader
>   reader)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource.WrapExceptionAndRethrow(String
>   fullPathToFile, Exception ex)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.FilePackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullPathToFile)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.DirectoryPackageJsonSource..ctor(String
>   fullDirectoryPath)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   at Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NodeModules..ctor(IRootPackage
>   parent, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)    at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.RootPackage..ctor(String
>   fullPathToRootDirectory, Boolean showMissingDevOptionalSubPackages)
>   at
>   Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.SPI.NpmController.d__1.MoveNext()<---

I tried this links that may fix the issue, but none of those help me:

1. [Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. ---> Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException: Error reading package.json. The file may be parseable JSON but may contain objects with duplicate properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/208)
2. [Global packages not loading due to Microsoft.NodejsTools.Npm.PackageJsonException with npm dependency](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/533)
3. [Error - Cannot load global packages." after fresh install of node/npm](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/476)